# How can I configure an OBD ELM327 cable to work with an ICS tablet?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-host-mode

I bought an OBD ELM327 USB cable in order to use it with Torque Pro since Ice Cream Sandwich USB host capabilities and the Torque website claims that it works. The problem is that when I connect the OBD adapter to my tablet it simply doesnt do anything, but I expected the choose application window to pop up. I downloaded a usb device app and I can see that it is connected, but it doesn't recognize it. How can I configure it so when I connect it the choose app window pops up?

Comment: Just a cable? As for the choose-app dialog, it usually doesn't pop up if you have nothing to handle the event.  Do you have an app that is supposed to work with this?

Comment: Its not really a cable, it is the OBDII ELM327 usb adapter.It is supposed to work with torque pro an app that specializes on car diagnostics via bluetooth and wifi but it also has the option to work with usb since ICS has the host capability.In the app's manual it says:Plug the usb and when the pop up window comes up for choosing an app to work with, check torque pro.I did this many times including when the engine was on but nothing happened.@MatthewRead

Comment: I downloaded an app called USB device info.It has two windows.Android and Linux.When i plug the usb, in the android window nothing comes up but in the linux one it recognizes it and gives me some device info @MatthewRead

Comment: It may be that your specific tablet doesn't support the necessary functions through USB OTG. It may only support storage and HID (keyboards & mice). Can you not use the adapter with bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

I have the kyocera event that also runs Ice Cream Sandwich and in turn is rooted... ...using kernel tuner(very old version) I saw it as well and tired it myself, it did work for about a minute then a portion of the system went bad and restarted. After it restarted the option was no longer visible in the app. In conclusion the option is there but full OTG  support is not. If you still want the support for OTG it may be best to flash a custom kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a otg cable to put your android into hostmode, that is if your tablet offers usb otg mode. I have this setup running on my galaxy s2 and my daughters fuhu nabi 2 , works great except for I need better shielded cables to prevent ef interference freezing data.

Comment: OP **is** using an OTG cable with an OTG-capable tablet, since he could connect the cable to his tablet and he has an app that shows the cable is connected. The problem must be that the tablet lacks drivers for the ELM327.

Answer (score 0):

on my Newsmy Carpad NU3001/NU5002 Android unit, i had to use a passive USB splitter hub 'octopus' and plugged it into the USB Host port.  Then I took a mini-USB cable and plugged that into the USB OTG port on the android box.  Then I plugged both the miniUSB cable and the ELM USB OBD2 adapter into the usb hub dongle octopus.  Then and only then was Torque able to see the adapter.  Basically I had to use both USB OTG and USB Host ports to get the USB ELM adapter working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this exact combination of equipment, but you probably need to

1. connect the ELM device to the tablet
2. connect the ELM device
   to the vehicle
3. turn the vehicle ignition on, but don't start the
   engine; in other words turn the key to position II.